# Require Python module to load machine learning model at startup - Will Gunicorn with Flask launch a new process for each request?

Tags: flask, machine-learning, gunicorn

I have a code developed in Python which reads models and based on the input it receives it checks the model and returns a confidence score. To make this model usable by other services I plan to use Flask. I am planning to use Gunicorn with Nginx infront of Flask to handle HTTP Requests.

When I add threaded as True in the app.run params I am able to send multiple requests at a time and not wait one after the other. However do the workers launch a new process for each request? Would this mean that for every request my 800 MB model will be loaded? Am I missing something?!

Comment: No. Unlike old cgi scripts, wsgi app should stay in memory if everything is set up correctly

Comment: How do i verify if I have set up correctly?

Comment: Log when loading the model, should happen once for each worker, on startup not when a request comes

Comment: Also, this kind of heavy lifting is best done outside of any web server, in a background process (see [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/))

Comment: @Igonato Wouldn't that mean that I would be using as much memory as the number of workers? I have 8 CPUs, so that would mean approx 6.4GB of RAM. Is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: I don't think there is a generic solution for this problem. Can you set up a minimal working example, so I can play with it?

Comment: @Igonato I will try setting up a minimal example. In my file, I wrote 

'@'app.before_first_request
  def _run_on_start():
      print "Testing1"

This got printed only once on the first request I received. Doesnt this mean that I can do something similar to load my model and it will load only once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145163/discussion-between-igonato-and-user1692342).